# Access compilation.assets after "copy-webpack-plugin" (Webpack)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a custom Webpack plugin, which would create manifest files listing all of a web game's assets (for the purpose of preloading them).

I can get a list of assets (`compilation.assets`), when I hook to "emit", but my assets are missing from this list. They are static and are copied via "copy-webpack-plugin", so I presume they are missing, because it hasn't run yet.

I can hook to "afterEmit" and get all assets, including the ones I need, but the emit phase is already finished, and I can't emit my manifest file.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing?

```
class CreateAssetPathsTextFiles 
{
  apply(compiler) 
  {
    compiler.hooks.emit.tapPromise(
      'CreateAssetPathsTextFiles',
      async ( compilation ) => 
      {
        const jsonData = { paths:[] }
        for ( const filepath in compilation.assets ) 
        {
          /// ... these are before "copy-webpack-plugin" did its work
        }
        const json = JSON.stringify( jsonData, null, 2 );
        compilation.assets['filelist.json'] = { source: () => json, size: () => json.length };
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you figured this out?